# phpmyadmin error

Tags: phpmyadmin

Phpmyadmin showing error. Help me to rectify.

[image]

> phpMyAdmin tried to connect to the MySQL server, and the server
>   rejected the connection. You should check the host, username and
>   password in your configuration and make sure that they correspond to
>   the information given by the administrator of the MySQL server.

Comment: Have you done what the error message suggests? Is Mysql running?

Answer (score 1):

You have most probably misconfigured phpmyadmin.

With `sudo dpkg-reconfigure phpmyadmin` you can reconfigure your installation.